# Julia: How to generate new immutable struct by modifying original immutable struct at user-supplied field?

Tags: struct, julia, metaprogramming

Suppose I have some immutable struct, e.g.

```
struct Person
           name::Symbol
           age::Int
       end;
```

I want to write a function

```
function copyWithModification(original_person::Person, fieldToChange::String, valueForNewField)::Person
```

that returns a new Person struct just like the old one except that the value of the field specified in fieldToChange has been set to valueForNewField. How do I do this?

My current attempt uses [Setfield](https://github.com/jw3126/Setfield.jl) and metaprogramming

```
using Setfield
function copyWithModification(original_person::Person, fieldToChange::String, valueForNewField)::Person
    return eval(Meta.parse("@set original_person." * fieldToChange * " = " * string(valueForNewField)))
end
```

This does not work because the eval is performed in global scope and thus does not have access to the original_person object:

```
julia> struct Person
                  name::Symbol
                  age::Int
              end;

julia> using Setfield

julia> function copyWithModification(original_person::Person, fieldToChange::String, valueForNewField)::Person
           return eval(Meta.parse("@set original_person." * fieldToChange * " = " * string(valueForNewField)))
       end
copyWithModification (generic function with 1 method)

julia> person_local_scope = Person(:test, 10)
Person(:test, 10)

julia> copyWithModification(person_local_scope, "age", 20)
ERROR: UndefVarError: original_person not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /Users/lionstarr/.julia/packages/Setfield/XM37G/src/sugar.jl:182
 [2] eval at ./boot.jl:330 [inlined]
 [3] eval(::Expr) at ./client.jl:425
 [4] copyWithModification(::Person, ::String, ::Int64) at ./REPL[3]:2
 [5] top-level scope at REPL[5]:1

julia>
```

I should note I am not concerned with the performance of this code; it will only be called once or twice.  The point is to save code replication and human error as the struct I actually want to use this code on is a lot larger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not concerned with performance, using plain introspection is fine and very simple in your case:

```
function copy_with_modification1(original::T, field_to_change, new_value) where {T}
    val(field) = field==field_to_change ? new_value : getfield(original, field)
    T(val.(fieldnames(T))...)
end
```

For example, it yields the following results:

```
julia> struct Person
           name::Symbol
           age::Int
       end

julia> p = Person(:Joe, 42)
Person(:Joe, 42)

julia> using BenchmarkTools
julia> @btime copy_with_modification1($p, :age, 43)
  666.924 ns (7 allocations: 272 bytes)
Person(:Joe, 43)
```

In order to regain efficiency, the same kind of technique can be implemented in such a way that listing fields happens at compile-time. Here is an example using a [generated function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#Generated-functions-1):

```
# Can't have closures inside generated functions, so the helper function
# is declared outside
function val_(original, field, field_to_change, new_value)
    field == field_to_change ? new_value : getfield(original, field)
end

@generated function copy_with_modification2(original, field_to_change, new_value)
    # This is the "compile-time" part
    T = original           # here `original` refers to the type of the argument
    fields = fieldnames(T) # fieldnames is called compile-time

    # This is the "run-time" part
    quote
        # We broadcast only over `fields`, other arguments are treated as scalars
        $T(val_.(Ref(original), $fields, Ref(field_to_change), Ref(new_value))...)
    end
end
```

The performance is now much better:

```
julia> @btime copy_with_modification2($p, :age, 43)
  2.533 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
Person(:Joe, 43)
```

Answer (score 2):

Such function is already defined in `Setfield` and there is no need to reinvent the wheel!

```
julia> using Setfield

julia> p = Person(:Smith, 10)
Person(:Smith, 10)

julia> setproperties(p, age=20)
Person(:Smith, 20)
```

More than one field can be set at a time, see `?setproperties` for more details.

Comment: They now suggest using https://github.com/JuliaObjects/Accessors.jl (as far as I get it). :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use metaprogramming for this. I think this "normal" function manages to do what you need.

```
function Person(p :: Person,fieldtochange,newvalue)
   
    newparams = [] # This array will store a new list of parameters 

    # This loop will iterate in all the fields (obtained via [fieldnames][1]) 
    # of the struct Person and compare with the given field,
    # if it coincides, adds the new value to the newparams array,
    # if not, get the values of the original person using
    # getproperty and add them to the array.

    for currentfield in fieldnames(Person) 
       if currentfield == fieldtochange
           push!(newparams,newvalue)
       else
           push!(newparams,getproperty(p,currentfield)) #[2]
       end
   end
   return Person(newparams...) #Construct a new person with the  new parameters
                               # using '...' for [splatting][3].
end
```

In this case I named the function "Person" to make it another constructor but you can change the name to the one you wanted.

[1](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#...) https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.fieldnames

[2] https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.getproperty

[3] https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#...